# Python3 Iterate over a file printing multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a text file(test.txt) with the following lines

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

It's easy to iterate over it

```
fh=open("./test.txt")
for x in fh:
    print(x)
fh.close()
```

What I'm trying to do is print lines 2 lines, like this,

```
line0 
line2
line1
line3
```

So essentially I'm trying to access the current line and the a line 2 lines down from the current location. I have been messing around with the itererator but not got anywhere. 
I'd welcome all input please.
Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand your desired output.  Is it like `0 2 1 3 5 4 6 8 7 9`, or `0 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4 6 5 7 6 8 7 9 ...`? Does the iterator stop when the line two below the current line is the last line of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.tee` to replicate the file iterator, skip the first two values of the second iterator returned by `tee`, and then `zip` the two iterators to produce the desired pairs of lines so that you can `chain` and `join` them for output:

```
from itertools import tee, chain
l, n = tee(fh)
next(n)
next(n)
print(''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(l, n))))
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
line0
line2
line1
line3
line2
line4
line3
line5
line4
line6
line5
line7
line6
line8
line7
line9
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to just read the whole file:

```
fh = open("./test.txt")
lines = fh.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines) - 2):
    print(lines[i])
    print(lines[i + 2])
```

Comment: This unnecessarily reads the entire file into memory, which can cause performance and memory issues when dealing with large files.

Answer (score 1):

and Welcome to Stackoverflow

You can try this.

```
left = next(fh)
center = next(fh)
while True:
   try:
     right = next(fh)
   except StopIteration:
     break
   print('{}\n{}'.format(left, right)
   left = center
   center = right
```

This returns

```
line0
line2
line1
line3
line2
line4
line3
line5
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

also an option which does not read the whole file in one go but just stores 2 lines at a time:

```
txt = """line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9"""

with StringIO(txt) as file:
    a, b = next(file), next(file)
    for c in file:
        print(a, end='')
        print(c, end='')
        a, b = b, c
```

with the output

```
line0
line2
line1
line3
line2
line4
line3
line5
line4
line6
line5
line7
line6
line8
line7
line9
```

you'd have to replace the `StringIO` part with your file of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator that handles any number of lines including odd length files:

```
def alternate(f):
    write = False
    for line in f:
        if not write:
            keep = line
        else:
            yield line
            yield keep
        write = not write
    if write: # handle odd-line-count files.
        yield line

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in alternate(f):
        print(line,end='')
```

Example input (odd length):

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```

Output:

```
line1
line0
line3
line2
line5
line4
line7
line6
line9
line8
line10
```

Comment: Nice I like the idea of using a generator for this as the text source could be large